# How to Access Object Properties w/ Static Callback?

Tags: c++, callback, static-methods

**Description:**

I'm having an issue with a 3rd party library, this library is called TVideoGrabber. When I pass the address of my function to the library I lose access to MyClass methods and properties from the callback method.

```
m_pAPI->SetCallback(OnCallback);
```

This line above passes the OnCallback address to the API. Once The API calls the OnCallback method when it has an update. This works fine so far.

**The line in question:**

```
a->SetA(api->GetNumber());
```

I know that the syntax above is not correct, but it should illustrate what I'm trying to do, I would like to Set the Value of A from the API.

**The Problem:**

when the API calls the OnCallback function the sender is the address of the m_pAPI object and I do not have access to the MyClass object.

**The Question:**

How can I access the MyClass object

**Here is a full code example:**

```
void MyClass::OnCallback(void* Object, void* sender) 
{
     API* api = (API*)(sender);

    // NO ACCESS TO MyClass properties or methods :( 
    a->SetA(api->GetNumber());  
}

class MyClass
{
    public:
          MyClass();
          ~MyClass();

          static void CALLBACK OnCallback(void* Object, void* sender);
          void SetA(int a);
          int GetA() const;

    private:
          API* m_pAPI;
          int a;  
}

MyClass::MyClass()
      : a(0)
{
    m_pAPI = new API;

    // Register for callbacks
    m_pAPI->SetCallback(OnCallback);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete m_pAPI;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass my;
    std::cout << "Value from API is " << my.GetA();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance! Looking forward to your Replys!

Comment: For this to work, there must be SOME connection between the api and your myclass. The typical case is that it's passed in along with OnCallback. Or possibly that "this" is saved as part of SetCallback and passed as "object". But with the given code, that's not possible to say.

Comment: If they have SetCallback(), they should have something called SetSender(), or SetCallBackSender(). Usually, when SetCallback is defined in the third-party API's it has two parameters: the CallBack function pointer, and the void* for the sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace:

```
m_pAPI = new API;
```

by:

```
m_pAPI = new API(this);
```

this will use the 2nd constructor of the CVideoGrabber class from TVideoGrabber.h:

```
CVideoGrabber (void* classPtr);
```

and the pointer of the instance of your class will be returned by the "sender" parameter of the callback events.